# Adding AutoScroll inside a DIV-Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

How do I add an auto scroll function to the below file?

By *auto scroll* I mean it automatically scrolls to the bottom within the scrollable area and then start from the top again.

I tried different JavaScript code, but none of it worked.

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-heading"><?php echo $heading_title; ?></div>
    <div class="box-content">
        <?php foreach ($all_news as $news) { ?>
            <div align="center">
            </div>
            <div style="
                width: 98%;
                height: 200px;
                overflow-y:auto;">

                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://domain.com/file.php"></script>
                <div id="feedmain" class="feed11"><a href="http://www.domain.com">PFeed</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

The file.php we are loading is only an HTML table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `overflow-y:scroll` instead of `overflow-y:auto`.

Comment: that is not the point, the point is to auto scroll, it means when it loads, it automatically goes from the top to the bottom and vise versa.

Comment: If that is the case, use `scrollTop` to first go to bottom then to top.

Comment: What you are showing here is going to show the page from bottom instead of the top but thats nit the case here. What I need is when its loaded it starts scrolling to the bottom of the page automatically without user doing it and then start from the beginning again

Comment: Yes, you can made it using 'scrollTop' with jquery. But, showing the top again needs complex programming. For this you can try jquery scroll plugins.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me.

```
var objDiv = document.getElementById("your_div");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```

Comment: Thank you @vinshnu I tried it it doesn't work for the above code.

Answer (score -1):

Use CSS

```
.divClass{
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

Comment: What you are showing here is going to show the scroll and it is already in the code. What I need is when its loaded it starts scrolling to the bottom of the page automatically without user doing it and then start from the beginning again